# Please welcome your new moderators

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image]
[image]
[image]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.** Until that time, we're very lucky to have upstanding members of the community willing to volunteer their time for this.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Well, congratulations to the three of them.

Comment: Congratulations Yannis, Semaphore, and HDE! :D

Comment: Congratulations!  Well deserved kudos!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations! All of you deserve this and will be excellent moderators.

If I may make one suggestion: can you only use the private moderator chat room to discuss sensitive issues involving specific users, and keep all policy discussions on [the main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23261/the-pantheon) as much as possible? We have a dedicated user base, and it would be a waste to have private conversations when there is no need to do so.

Comment: Absolutely. We'll keep private what needs to be private, and reduce some chat room clutter.